# Is there a way to figure out what data MySQL copies to tmp table? See inside

Tags: mysql

I execute a query and wait. If I execute `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` while query executes, I can see "Copying to tmp table" in State column. How do I know what data (from which table) does MySQL copy to tmp table? Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the query, could depend on what part of the query was executing at the time you executed the command. If you want to optimise the query use Explain